# Add two or more script jquery in content editor web part Sharepoint 2007

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, content-editor

i want to insert in my NewForm.aspx two or more script in jquery. I wrote the code in a Content Editor web part as many online tutorial.

I have two script that work fine separately, but when i merge the script doesn't work (exactly work just one of two).

This is my code in Content editor:

```
    <p>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.js">
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function HideColumn(targetColumn, hideColumn) {  
        var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + hideColumn + "']");
        $("input[Title='" + targetColumn + "']").bind('click',function() { 

            if($(this).is(':checked')) {                  
                columnObj.closest("tr").show();
             }
             else {
                columnObj.closest("tr").hide();
             }
        });      
       }

     $(document).ready(function() {
            HideColumn('sino','descrizione');
        });
    </script>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.js">
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function HideColumn(targetColumn, hideColumn) {  
        var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + hideColumn + "']");
        $("select[Title='" + targetColumn + "']").bind('click',function() { 

            if($(this).val() == "Pippo") {                
                columnObj.closest("tr").show();
             }
             else {
                columnObj.closest("tr").hide();
             }
        });      
       }

     $(document).ready(function() {
            HideColumn('Scelta','descrizione');
        });
    </script>
</p>
```

Thank for your help,

EDIT SOLVED:

```
This is the correct code:

<p>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.js">
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function HideColumn(targetColumn1, hideColumn1, targetColumn2, hideColumn2) {  
        var columnObj1 = $("input[Title='" + hideColumn1 + "']");
        $("input[Title='" + targetColumn1 + "']").bind('click',function() { 

            if($(this).is(':checked')) {                  
                columnObj1.closest("tr").show();
             }
             else {
                columnObj1.closest("tr").hide();
             }
        });

        var columnObj2 = $("input[Title='" + hideColumn2 + "']");
    $("select[Title='" + targetColumn2 + "']").bind('click',function() { 

        if($(this).val() == "Pippo") {                
            columnObj2.closest("tr").show();
         }
         else {
            columnObj2.closest("tr").hide();
         }
    });       
       }
      $(document).ready(function() {
            HideColumn('sino','descrizione','Scelta','Titolo');
        });
    </script>

</p>
```

Regards,
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues, some that will outright break this (the duplicate function definitions) & others that are less-than-optimal design. You don't need to load the jQuery library twice and you shouldn't define the same function twice with different contents.

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideColumn(targetColumn, hideColumn) {  
        var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + hideColumn + "']");
        $("input[Title='" + targetColumn + "']").bind('click',function() { 

            if($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).val() == "Pippo") {                  
                columnObj.closest("tr").show();
             }
             else {
                columnObj.closest("tr").hide();
             }
        });      
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        HideColumn('sino','descrizione');
        HideColumn('Scelta','descrizione');
    });
</script>
```

To also have the ability to hide certain columns on initial page load, consider the below:

**UPDATE**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideColumnOnLoad(hideColumn) {
        $("input[Title='" + hideColumn + "']").closest("tr").hide();
    }
    function HideColumnOnClick(targetColumn, hideColumn) {  
        var columnObj = $("input[Title='" + hideColumn + "']");
        $("input[Title='" + targetColumn + "']").bind('click',function() { 

            if($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).val() == "Pippo") {                  
                columnObj.closest("tr").show();
             }
             else {
                columnObj.closest("tr").hide();
             }
        });      
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        HideColumnOnLoad('descrizione');
        HideColumnOnClick('sino','descrizione');
        HideColumnOnClick('Scelta','descrizione');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...it works! Another question..it's possible to hide a row when i open a new form? In my case "sino" by default is "no" but i see "descrizione". When i open form i want to hide "descrizione". Thanks!

Comment: I tried to hide a row of "date" field. It hides only the field, but not the row. I have to use different setting? Thank you very much!

Comment: RE: Date fields, this is because SharePoint uses a nested table as the markup for the input & icon that pops the calendar date picker. In these case, your selector would need to be: columnObj.closest('td.ms-formbody').closest('tr').hide();

Comment: Also, if you're looking to achieve the same in all one function, I'd modify the HideColumnOnLoad function to accept a 2nd parameter of field type. Said parameter would then be used to apply necessary conditional logic based on the field type (chances are Person/Group fields will also have a similar quirk, if not others). If you need help with that, I suggest posting a new question though; not sure if we're abusing the Comments here...

Comment: Thaks again. You saved my life :)